# How to create custom SSLSocketFactory?

Tags: java, ssl, mocking

I'm trying to create my own implementation of [`javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html), in order to catch all HTTP/SSL requests, send by a third-party library, and log them. This is how the factory is called in that library (it's commons-httpclient):

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
// ...
return SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);
```

Current implementation used is `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl`. How can I change it to my own custom class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html:

> (...) The default implementation can be
>   changed by setting the value of the
>   "ssl.SocketFactory.provider" security
>   property (in the Java security
>   properties file) to the desired class.

<strike>More information about defining your own security policy file can be found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html.</strike>

It seems that you can only change that property at the JSM level, and not for each project. In Windows, you can find that file at Java\jre6\lib\security\java.security.

Comment: There is a way to override security props with system property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4521741/603516